# fancybox ajax loading error

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

i'm using fancybox plugin to load ajax page , bu sometimes i get this error
 :

**"The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."**

```
<a href="login.html" class="login fancybox.ajax">Log In</a>
```

and my jquery code  is  :

```
$(function(){
$('.login').fancybox();

});
```

Comment: where do you get this error? console.log?

Comment: i get it on fancybox popup

Comment: can you access login.html otherwise ?

Comment: yes, this problem appear sometimes, on localhost works fine